# Why ActiveSupport core extension not added as module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I was reading the ActiveSupport core_ext source, and saw that it directly open and extend the core ruby class, e.g: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/conversions.rb
. Doesn't that make it harder for us to know wether some method is from activesupport or actually provided by ruby itself (e.g via `Method#owner`)?

Why doesn't it use something like prepending/including a module to give its added functionality? E.g:

```rb
module StringConversionExtension
  def to_time
    # some implementation
  end
end

String.prepend(StringExtension)
```

Is there any historical/performance reason the implementation is as it is now?

Comment: Just want to point out that `Method#source_location` will tell you if it came from ActiveSupport even if `owner` doesnt.

Comment: I forgot about that! But the question still remains, why don't ActiveSupport extends the core class by prepending/including the module?

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't it use something like prepending/including a module to give its added functionality? E.g:

Possibly to either:

- Minimize the amount of code in Rails (since your proposed approach  is a bit more verbose), or
- Minimize the number of methods/constants/modules in existence as well as in the core classes, since in your proposed approach the core String class would have the new method *and* it would now be including the StringExtensions module.